# Magento open description tab on product detail page on onclick link

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, magento-1.8

I need to open the product description tab on the product detail page. I have one link on product detail page. When I click on that link, it opens the product description tab and displays it on top. User redirect on the product description link so the user can see there product description. Do you any idea about to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

In product Detail Page **`(catalog/product/view.phtml),`** you can get product description by :

```
$description = $_product->getDescription();
```

Or

```
$description = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getDescription()), 'description');
```

Create your own html tabs and add description in there from where user can view it without getting redirected to any other page. :)

Comment: product description tab already show on page. but how i can display it when user click on link which is display in same product detail page. i already used id option but there is not working